# adding a page to github pages 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, github-pages

I created a website on GitHub pages and it worked but when I tried to add a page "site" it kept on giving me 404 errors when I tried to reach the "site page"

this is my github page for better insight: https://github.com/Dana1384/coursera-test.git
original website: https://dana1384.github.io/coursera-test/

When I try to reach the "site" page: https://dana1384.github.io/coursera-test/site/

Answer (score 1):

On the "404 page," it is mentioned that, *"For root URLs (like `http://example.com/`) you must provide an index.html file."* So, I think you need to add the index.html file in the root and you can define a link to your folder site to test if it works.

Comment: I offered you a pull request on your repository

Comment: oh my god thank you so muchhh

Comment: wait what was the problem?